# Where we are setting http://localhost:8081/ in React Native App for Android

Tags: android, react-native, npm, mobile, localhost

I am trying to create an android app with React Native. I am new to React native.
My question is can we load the index.js file from like https://domain_name.com/appname/index.
or where we are setting http:localhost:8081 for react native?

Answer (score 0):

For development, you can customize the port number by supplying the `--port` argument to the command `react-native start`, as [stated here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/fa73dd1c30ff60da87717ae3c2043ffdd7d12257/docs/commands.md#--port-number-2).

You can theoretically expose the packager server to the internet with tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), and configure bundler via the [developer debug menu](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu) accordingly. I haven't tried it personally though.

For production, you can make your most up-to-date js bundle accessible over the internet via either [expo-updates](https://docs.expo.io/bare/updating-your-app/), or [react-native-code-push](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push).